# Resampling and doing Linear Interpolation in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have a data which contains `Id, DateTime and Value` Column. Data are supposed to be collected in every 10 mins. However, there are some data which has gaps of over 10 mins ( for example gaps of over 20 mins, 1hr, 2 hr). Data are collected for one full month.  I want to use re sampling and use linear interpolation on my `Value Column` so that every `Value columns` contain data for fixed interval of time ( let say for every 1 hr and (weekly based)).

This is my sample data

```
 Id DateTime              Value
20  2018-04-08 00:28:52     10
20  2018-04-08 00:38:34     11  
20  2018-04-08 00:48:57     9
20  2018-04-08 01:18:22     7   
............................
205  2018-04-08 01:08:28    11
205  2018-04-08 01:18:33    13
205  2018-04-08 01:27:22    8
205  2018-04-08 01:37:02    7
205  2018-04-08 01:56:44    6
205  2018-04-08 02:16:14    10

.....
2053  2018-04-08 02:06:03   11
2053  2018-04-08 02:17:10   12
2053  2018-04-08 02:26:33   8
2053  2018-04-08 02:36:53   9
2053  2018-04-08 03:26:33   13
```

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks

Comment: What data are resampling? Do you need `df.set_index('DateTime').resample('1H').mean()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe need:

```
print (df)

      Id            DateTime  Value
0     20 2018-04-08 00:28:52     10
1     20 2018-04-08 00:38:34     11
2     20 2018-04-08 00:48:57      9
3     20 2018-04-08 01:18:22      7
4    205 2018-04-08 01:08:28     11
5    205 2018-04-08 01:18:33     13
6    205 2018-04-08 01:27:22      8
7    205 2018-04-08 01:37:02      7
8    205 2018-04-08 01:56:44      6
9    205 2018-04-08 02:16:14     10
10  2053 2018-04-08 10:06:03     11
11  2053 2018-04-08 10:17:10     12
12  2053 2018-04-08 10:26:33      8
13  2053 2018-04-08 10:36:53      9
14  2053 2018-04-08 10:26:33     13
```

---

```
df = df.set_index('DateTime')['Value'].resample('1H').mean().interpolate()
print (df)

DateTime
2018-04-08 00:00:00    10.000000
2018-04-08 01:00:00     8.666667
2018-04-08 02:00:00    10.000000
2018-04-08 03:00:00    10.075000
2018-04-08 04:00:00    10.150000
2018-04-08 05:00:00    10.225000
2018-04-08 06:00:00    10.300000
2018-04-08 07:00:00    10.375000
2018-04-08 08:00:00    10.450000
2018-04-08 09:00:00    10.525000
2018-04-08 10:00:00    10.600000
Freq: H, Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

If need `resample` per groups also add `groupby` with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same `DatetimeIndex` per each unique `Id`s:

```
df = df.set_index('DateTime').groupby('Id')['Value'].resample('1H').mean()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], pd.date_range(df.index.levels[1].min(), df.index.levels[1].max(), freq='h')])
df = df.reindex(mux)
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())
```

---

```
print (df)

20    2018-04-08 00:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 01:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 02:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 03:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 04:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 05:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 06:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 07:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 08:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 09:00:00     7.0
      2018-04-08 10:00:00     7.0
205   2018-04-08 00:00:00     NaN
      2018-04-08 01:00:00     9.0
      2018-04-08 02:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 03:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 04:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 05:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 06:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 07:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 08:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 09:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 10:00:00    10.0
2053  2018-04-08 00:00:00     NaN
      2018-04-08 01:00:00     NaN
      2018-04-08 02:00:00     NaN
      ... 
      2018-04-08 07:00:00     NaN
      2018-04-08 08:00:00     NaN
      2018-04-08 09:00:00     NaN
      2018-04-08 10:00:00    10.6
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Another solution if need `interpolate` each group separately:

```
df = (df.set_index('DateTime')
       .groupby('Id')['Value']
       .resample('1H')
       .mean()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate()))

print (df)


Id    DateTime           
20    2018-04-08 00:00:00    10.0
      2018-04-08 01:00:00     7.0
205   2018-04-08 01:00:00     9.0
      2018-04-08 02:00:00    10.0
2053  2018-04-08 10:00:00    10.6
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, but is this re-sampling independent to the Id ? May be I need to `groupby` with `Id` first and then resample it ?

Comment: @user3280146 - If want data resampling per Id also, not so easy, but if need same datetimes per each `Id` need `reindex` with `MultiIndex`, last `interpolate` per groups